# GWT Cell Browser Real Time Update Problem

Tags: gwt, user-interface, treeview, widget

Does someone know how to update a cell browser view on the spot. I am trying refresh and flush but it is not working. I am having to remove the cell browser from the widget and then place it again.

For e.g. If I have a leaf and wants now to add a node to leaf and make it a parent. When I add the children to the leaf (say leaf A), I need to click on another item of the cell browser and then after clicking on another item, then when I click on leaf A which is now a parent it is only then that I see the newly added children

Therefore the problem I am getting it that whenever I add a children to a leaf to make it a parent, I does not see the change on the spot. I need to click on another item and then return back to see the change

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok, I did it:

In the tree model, the isleaf, i made it return false always. then when adding a node to a leaf, since the browser for the leaf is already open, a a node to the leaf, then just refresh the data provider

Comment: Would be nice if you'd publish the solution here anyway for the rest of the community.

Comment: in the tree model, the isleaf, i made it return false always. then when adding a node to a leaf, since the browser for the leaf is already open, a a node to the leaf, then just refresh the data provider

Comment: Why do you always post "I found the answer" to your queries, but then neglect to tell us what it is? Don't you think that's a little abusive of this community?

Comment: @Caffeine Coma, the answer was already here on dec 12, and your comments was on jan 15!!